# Binding combobox in DataTemplate to a different ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, binding, datatemplate

I have 2 ObservableCollection lists, which we can call A and B, then I have a GridView that I want to bind to list A and a ComboBox INSIDE that GridView, that I want to bind to list B.
I've set the ItemsSource property of the GridView by code: gridview.ItemsSource=A (and it works!). About the ComboBox its instance it is not available by code, I suppose because its definition it is enclosed between the DataTemplate tags; so I wonder how to bind the combo to list B, either by code or by XAML.

Follows the XAML code:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="lstReplacements" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}" Header="Wrong text" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Word}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}" Header="Replacement" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Replacement}" />
                            <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}" Header="Type"  Width="30">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{??????}" DisplayMemberPath="??????"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="cmbCorrectionType"  Width="75" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Thanks in advance for the support!
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this control is in UserControl and you have ***set DataContext of that UserControl to the class instance where your both collections CollectionA and CollectionB resides***.

You can then bind using `RelativeSource`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.CollectionB,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                              AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Also you can set DataContext of ListView to the class instance and all you need to do is change AncestorType to ListView in place of UserControl in above binding.